# Guessing to find out prime numbers of N

Tags: numerical-methods, logarithms, approximation, exponentiation, prime-factorization

Hello and good evening.

Well, the factors of N=39 are 3 and 13.
When i calculate k1 and k2:
\begin{equation}
    k1 =\log{(3)}/ \log(39) = 0.2998754... \\
    k2 =\log{(13)}/ \log(39) = 0.7001246... \\
\end{equation}
i see that k1 + k2 equals to 1.

that means:
\begin{equation}
    1 = k1 + k2 \\
    3 = 39^{k1} \\
    13 = 39^{k2} \\
\end{equation}
When i take the square root of 39, i get:
\begin{equation} 
\sqrt{39} = 6.24 \\
39^{0.5} = 6.24
\end{equation}
The main idea is to calculate the .24 decimal off and variate the 0.5 exponent to the values above like k1 and k2 so that i can get the factors 3 and 13.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thanks for reading.

Edit:

The issue is the following one:

When i get the square root of 39, then i will have a value of N.
I just wanted to calculate the k1 and k2 values without brute-forcing by a computer code. When i increment 0.5 to something 0.51, it will decrement the other 0.5 to 0.49 till the integer prime values have been found of N like 3 and 13.

\begin{equation} 
39^{0.51} = 6.47 \\
39^{0.49} = 6.020 \\
... till \\
39^{0.2998754} = 3 \\
39^{0.7001246} = 13
\end{equation}

Comment: This is not clear.  Perhaps it would help if you provided an example of what you were trying to do.

Comment: Yes, i am going to edit my post now.

Comment: "The main idea is to calculate the .24 decimal off and variate the 0.5 exponent to the values above like k1 and k2 so that i can get the factors 3 and 13."  I do not understand what this excerpt is saying.  Could you please re-state this?

Comment: A couple of problems here: [1] In effect, you are looking for two numbers $a,b$ such that $a \times b = \left(\sqrt{n}\right)^2$, where $n$ is the number you are trying to factorize.  This is fine for a number like $39$, but you will have trouble of one sort, if $n = 37$, and trouble of another sort if $n = 45$. [2] If I understand your proposed algorithm, you want to find two numbers $r$ and $s$ such that $0 < r,s < 1$ and $(r + s) = 1$, and both $e^r$ and $e^s$ are integers.  This doesn't seem feasible.  ...see next comment

Comment: For example: rounding error may cause confusion between the factorization of $2400 = 2^5 \times 3 \times 5^2$ and $2401 = 7^4$.

Comment: If you are talking about the factorization of a number between $(10^6)$ and $(10^7)$ (for example) without resorting to a computer, then this would be a breakthrough, if you can pull it off.  I am just not seeing any way to do that.  Alternatively, if your algorithm involves the use of a computer, then you can instead, simply generate the complete list of primes less than $\sqrt{10^7}$, and then try each prime in turn.

Comment: I don't understand why going through exponents would be simpler than simply testing that 39/p has no remainder, unless there is a special reason why exponents here would help? Please explain...

Comment: I mean, is there a formula or anything in math that could make this example less complicated. I do not think i would code in python and brute force this example. It would really take a long hard time to get results for larger N integers. The main idea is here to make use of exponents to calculate the primes.

Comment: @PC1 I could be mistaken, but I think that what the OP is proposing is that he wants to find $r,s \in \Bbb{R^+}$ such that $e^r, e^s$ are both integers and $e^{r + s} = n$, where $n$ the number that you wish to factorize.  As I see it, the main stumbling block is trying to determine whether (for example) $e^r$ is an integer.  As you indicate, if you are going to confine your search for $r,s$ to $\log(p)$ where $p$ is a prime number $\leq \sqrt{n}$, then the approach does become pointless.

Comment: @user2661923, actually it looks to me like the OP would like some way to find an exponent $r$ such that $N^{0.5+r}$ and $N^{0.5-r}$ are both integers (without first finding the two integers).

Comment: The reason is why i want to use exponents for this case is, not to fall back to integers which i must test and probably have nothing with N and i want to keep the calculations on N and do not want to get rid of other primes which have not been calculated in this context.

Comment: @user2661923, just to clarify, we're both saying the same thing. I only meant that my version is a little more along the lines of the OP's description: They want to start at the square root of $N$ and vary the exponent up and down by equal amounts until they get to two integers.